# Hide empty fields in email - Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, email, contact-form-7

I've spend almost the whole day looking for an answer, but nothing helped..

I made a large form with Contact Form 7, but parts of the form will hide, depends on your choice. For example, if you choose '2 persons', there will two parts show up.

But, if I fill in the fields for one person (so the other fields are empty and hidden), the fields will visible in the email. I only want to see the filled fields in the email.

I'm sorry if I'm a bit unclear. Could use some help, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved!

I found a solution by myself, which was already in Contact Form 7. The fields in the e-mail were not on the same line, so when I checked "Exclude lines with blank mail-tags from output", nothing happend. I've put it all on the same line and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to implement your own custom email body component with,

```
    add_filter('wpcf7_mail_components','my_custom_mail', 10,2);
    function my_custom_mail($mail_component, $contact_form){
      $mail_component['subject']; //email subject
      $mail_component['sender']; //sender field (from)
      $mail_component['body']; //email body
      $mail_component['recipient']; //email recipient (to)
      $mail_component['additional_headers']; //email headers, cc:, bcc:, reply-to:
      $mail_component['attachments']; //file attachments if any

      $key_values = array();
      $tags = $contact_form->scan_form_tags(); //get your form tags
      foreach($tags as $tag){
        $field_name  = $tag['name'];
        if(isset($_POST[$field_name]) && !empty($_POST[$field_name])){
          //get all the submitted fields form your form
          $key_values[$field_name] = $_POST[$field_name]; 
        }
      }
      //you have all the submitted field-name => value pairs in the array $key_values
      //you can now reset you email body
      $body = "Dear ".$key_values['your-name'].',';
      ...
      $mail_component['body'] = $body;
      return $mail_component;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! But this solution will cost me too much time. I found a solution by myself, which was already in Contact Form 7. The fields in the e-mail were not on the same line, so when I checked "Exclude lines with blank mail-tags from output", nothing happend. I've put it all on the same line and now it works.

Comment: Ok, glad you found a solution, would you mind posting it as a separate solution so we can all share in the knowledge :)

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can use the free Plug-in Conditional Fields for Contact Form 7 by Jules Colle.

With it you can create groups of information.
Then you create a checkbox and in the settings you choose which group will appear when it's selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_mail_components', 'remove_blank_lines' );

function remove_blank_lines( $mail ) {
    if ( is_array( $mail ) && ! empty( $mail['body'] ) )
        $mail['body'] = preg_replace( '|\n\s*\n|', "\n\n", $mail['body'] );

    return $mail;
}
```

I have found the snippet here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-how-to-do-away-with-blank-lines-in-email-for-unfilled-form-items/ 
Depending on how you set up your email this might not work as this removes just the empty lines. Let me know if this works for you, and if not please provide the code from your email body, and an example email sent would be nice too.

Comment: Saw this code today too, but didn't work. It made the page even not able to see (don't know how to say it in English, hope you understand). I've checked if the function already existed in my code, but that wasn't the case.